# SQL Server Procedure to Update Column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

hello I am new to writing procedures in SQL Server.

I am trying to write a procedure to do some thing like this

LOGIC

```
If ( Table1. ColA.Value = Table2. colB.Value)
then
Table1.ColC.Value  = Table1. ColA.Value

(If Col A value of Table 1 = Col B value of Table 2)

THEN Update the value of Table1.ColC as the same value of Table1.ColA


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.stored1

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Var1 AS nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Var2 AS nvarchar(50)

SELECT @Var1 = Test.dbo.Unit.HMY
FROM Test.dbo.Unit

SELECT @Var2 = Test.dbo.UnitTypeExtract.HPROPERTY
FROM Test.dbo.UnitTypeExtract

SELECT CASE WHEN @Var1 = @Var2

THEN

UPDATE Test.dbo.Unit.UnitType = @Var1

END
```

The procedure runs well but no rows are affected. I am sure about the data as I compared it for similarity.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is more declarative than how you are trying to use it in your question. In very general terms, you tell it what produce rather than how to produce it. Your first example before the CREATE PROCEDURE piece is easier for me to understand, and here's how I interpret it:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET Table1.ColC = Table1.ColA
FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN
    Table2
    ON
        Table1.ColA = Table2.ColB;
```

I would also comment that the above usage seems a little off to me. What's causing that is I have not seen a reasonable need to update in a table to another value in the same table/same row. Review your logic carefully compared to what the business need is, because it seems off to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your update and your select case to:

```
IF @Var1 = @Var2 BEGIN

   UPDATE Test.dbo.Unit
   SET UnitType = @Var1

END
```

**But pay attention. This way you will update all rows. Is that really what you want?**

Comment: I did what u say but it gives Syntax error around upodate

Comment: Try again please. Now I see you were using select case. change to IF

Answer (score 0):

Your below code

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @Var1 = @Var2

THEN

UPDATE Test.dbo.Unit.UnitType = @Var1 <-- here missing set operator
```

Can be simplified to this directly

```
UPDATE Test.dbo.Unit set UnitType = @Var1 where @Var1 = @Var2
```

Comment: This will update every row in the table when that condition is met and does not consider the logic of how the value of Test.dbo.UnitTypeExtract.HPROPERTY relates to Test.dbo.Unit.HMY. The question is not phrased to make this clear, so I am partly assuming this would be important.

Comment: @KRichard, that's correct and I could interpret this only from OP question. again not pin pointing but your answer will also do the same :) "update all rows whichever matches the join condition". Hope that's what OP wants.

Comment: When I run this It updates the column but with only one value. How Do I run this for every row?

Comment: @user3614477, `How Do I run this for every row?` Check Richard's answer below. that's what you should be doing rather the way you are trying.